# iOS React Native Hermes not show in chrome inspect

Tags: react-native, google-chrome-devtools, metro-bundler, react-native-hermes

I just upgrade my iOS RN from 0.63 to 0.65. Then enable hermes in podfile.

I can start app normally, JSI is showing in developer menu, mean hermes is running.

I follow exactly guide from https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#debugging-js-on-hermes-using-google-chromes-devtools

But `console.log` code inside app print direct at metro windows. And when i go to `chrome://inspect/#devices`, nothing is showing at Remote Target like this
[image]

How i can get this work? My only option is disable hermes for a "not just a text log"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that, this is http://crbug.com/1492849, the fix is already in Canary, will be available in Stable in December.

Comment: This fixed for me, I guess we'll have to use canary to debug Hermes until this lands on stable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use hermes and debug your app use flipper to debug.
https://fbflipper.com